# Dates countries joined/left international organisations

Tags: data, data-cleaning

Does anyone know of a reliable data source containing the dates countries left or joined international organisations, for example,WTO, EU. etc? Ideally I'd like this going back to 1946. Even the year rather than exact date would be helpful.Bonus marks for it in a Python Package!

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. You can retrieve it from Wikipedia parsing the right artcile, it should be reliable imo. Aim for data stored in table, it should be easy to parse it.